# setting a maxDate with angular-strap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am trying to set a `maxDate` in a `angular-strap` `datepicker` in the `html`.  I want the `maxDate` to be tomorrow.  I have tried several ways, but none are working.  I have tried setting a date in the `html` to a `scope`d variable in the js like this:

js:

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
scope.tomorrow = tomorrow;
```

html:

```
<input ng-model="toDate" placeholder="DD MMM YYYY" bs-datepicker maxDate="{{tomorrow}}"/>
```

If I add it in the `provider`, everything works fine:

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
angular.extend($datepickerProvider.defaults, {
    autoclose: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd MMM yyyy',
    maxDate: tomorrow
});
```

But I don't want this behavior from all of my `datepicker`'s.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

change maxDate="{{tomorrow}}" to data-max-date="{{tomorrow}}"